# (Error in makefile)RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Tags: c++, makefile, ubuntu-10.04

This is my makefile:

```
delay:
    tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 0ms
test4_s_delay:delay
    ./a.out 10 10 1 2 3 1 1 20 | tee server_delay.txt
```

However, I am getting the following error on execution of the makefile:

```
root@superwii-laptop:/home/superwii/Desktop/Amogh# make test4_s_delay
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 0ms
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
make: *** [delay] Error 2
```

I am unable to get past this error. Please help.

Comment: should really be on serverfault ;)

Answer (score 7):

You would get this error, if qdisc root node already exists.
Try deleting the root qdisc

```
sudo tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
```

and try again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your executable `tc` is exiting with non-zero value of `2`.

Try running the command `tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 0ms` and see if it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

use replace instead of add

tc qdisc replace dev eth0 root netem delay. [Man page for tc](http://lartc.org/manpages/tc.txt) says :

> replace
>                 performs  a  nearly atomic remove/add on an existing node id. If
>                 the node does not exist yet it is created.